# How do I push changes into a branch that were not made in that GIT clone?

Tags: git, magento, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have just started using BitBucket and SourceTree for source control and am new to GIT. I have a plugin that I have developed on a local copy of Magento which gets installed on a clients site. They have given me access to their respository so that any changes I make can be pushed to their system.

Now, if I clone the repository, it is going to bring back the clients entire site, and not just the parts that are related to my plugin. Also, I can't obviously develop on a copy of their site as they have many different database configurations and server specific stuff.

I suppose my question is, how do I push any changes that I make to my local copy of my code back into their repository through SourceTree? Do I have to keep track of the files that I change myself, copy these into my cloned copy of the branch and then SourceTree will pick these up as changed so that I can commit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone their project on you local machine,

then you take your "Module" i'm assuming you use the best pratices in magento developing and make all your changes in modules separate from the rest of the magento core,

in this case, you can simply do a tar from your module like that:

In root of your project (the same place who have the index.php) on ssh tar -zcvf mymodule.tar.gz app/code/local/Namespace/Module/* app/etc/modules/namespace_module.xml 
and any thing else you have created for this function.

Then you go to your customer project(root) and make the "untar" 
tar -xvf mymodule.tar.gz

Now you can commit and push on the customer project, so they can do a pull on server side and bring all your modifications.

This is the right way to work with git.